# optimizing code for traversing a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I am doing a clustering algorithm, in which I have a dataset with (m) rows and (n) features. I create a Jaccard similarity matrix for the dataset that transforms my data set to a (m*m) similarity matrix.

After creating the similarity matrix I run a certain logic on the matrix to find few coordinates.

The logic I wrote actually traverses through half of the elements in the matrix but it takes a heck lot of time. As I am a newbie to python, my code is not too optimized but straight forward.

Please find my code below:

```
    similarity_dict={}
for (i,j), value in np.ndenumerate(matrix_for_cluster):
    if value>threshold and j>=i:
        if i in similarity_dict:
            similarity_dict[i].append(j)
            if i<>j:
                if j in similarity_dict:
                    similarity_dict[j].append(i)
                else:
                    similarity_dict[j]=[i]                    
        else:  
            similarity_dict[i]=[j]


Matrix for cluster is the similarity matrix, If any of the element's value is greater than the threshold value then the element index is stored in a dictionary.
```

I would really appreciate any help around optimizing the code

Comment: what about using a simple `y, x = np.where(matrix_for_cluster > threshold)`? That would give you the `y` and `x` coordinate vectors for where the condition is satisfied. Is this what you want?

Comment: @imaluengo,  thanks for the reply. But what I am looking is that for a particular row- for example, (0) i would like to fetch all the y axis coordinate like (1 (0,0),5(0,5),7(0,7)) that exceeds the threshold value and store it in a dictionary under the key (0). Similarly I would like to find all the y axis coordinate of each row and store those coordinate under the key row number.

Comment: @imaluengo, Okay gotcha,   Would it be optimized enough If I do something like .   np.where(matrix_for_cluster[i] > 0.4)   where i would loop through each row.

Comment: @Sam: can you provide an example input and expected output? I don't understand what you're doing with the `similarity_dict`. First you declare it empty, then you try to iterate through it, using the same indice name you did in your fist loop `i` (is this intentional?) and then you try to assing that key you're looping on, some value of `j`. But the dict is empty. Then you ask `similarity_dict[j]` a key which obviously isn't there? You haven't shared the full `similarity_dict` story here I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me that what you *want* or are trying to build looks like a graph. In that case, you can use the [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html) package:

```
>>> sim_matrix
array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 2, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 2, 0, 0]])
>>> sim_matrix[sim_matrix < 2] = 0 # apply your threshold
>>> sim_matrix
array([[0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 0, 0]])
```

with `sim_matrix` a numpy array:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> graph = nx.Graph(sim_matrix)
>>> graph.nodes()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> graph.edges(2)
[(2, 1), (2, 4)]
>>> graph.edges(4)
[(4, 0), (4, 2)]
```

Internally `networkx` works with python dictionaries, so its pretty much what you are trying to build, but already built for you.

NOTE: this would create a undirectional graph. Change `nx.Graph` by `nx.DiGraph` line if you want it directional.

EDIT: updated the example to make sim_matrix actually a symmetric matrix (undirectional graph).

Find more information about networkx and numpy [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/convert.html#module-networkx.convert_matrix).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the same but probably produce less VM ops:

```
for (i,j), value in np.ndenumerate(matrix_for_cluster):
    if value>threshold and j>=i:
        similarity_dict.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
        if i != j:
           similarity_dict.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
```

But in general, scipy and numpy (which you're already using I see) have much more optimized similarity of matrices and stuff like that, if you can keep all the work in num/scipy's native stuff, you'll get much much better performance.